# Website contents seem to be animating in without warning?

Tags: html, css, node.js, pug, stylus

When viewing my website (http://elsealabs.com/), it seems as if the content is animating inwards, even though I have no animations for such an event specified. How do I make this animation stop?

It is especially noticeable if you refresh the page and watch the download button or the navigation menu.

The Stylus code is here: https://gist.github.com/Connorelsea/a8d62c9dc7ac31069fc9

My Jade layout is here: https://gist.github.com/Connorelsea/b614e3754a1854625f1b

My Node.JS server code is here: https://gist.github.com/Connorelsea/198b7c2a1bace65d03c9

If anyone could even point me in the right direction to figuring out why this is happening, that would be great.

Comment: Can someone at least shed some light onto why this is being downvoted? It is a legitimate question that I have attempted to look for an answer to, and could not find one.

Comment: Try to set the width/height of your images on the img element.

Comment: The `.download` class and the menu items have got a `transition` property.

Comment: So simply having a transition makes it transition in initially like that? I thought that would make it transition simply when hovered over? How would I make it transition only when hovered over? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: No, `transition` applies to whenever some animatable CSS property changes. Even if you change a property with JS it will still do this smoothly with `transition`.

Comment: Then how can I make it not animate on startup, but do the animations on hover?

Comment: Not sure, I don’t even know why the sizes of the links _retroactively_ change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's the padding or margin transitioning at the page load. It is a bit weird, but the solution is to only apply a transition to the attributes you wish to have transition (and not "all" as you are here).

For the links, it would be something like

```
a {
    transition: font-size .2s, font-weight .2s;
}
```

On a sidenote, I suggest making the line-height a fixed height (in px) to make it less jumpy.